# [Play][Scala] Can I get the contents of multiple chained Actions?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to learn to use Action composition in the Play framework in Scala.

I understand the ability to do basic action composition and WrappedRequests, my question however is : Is it possible to access the contents of multiple WrappedRequests in a composed Action?

Let me explain, I have the following code:

```
   class RequestWithUser[A](val user: models.User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
    def UserAction(userId: Long) = new ActionBuilder[RequestWithUser] {
      def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (RequestWithUser[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        models.UsersDAO.findById(userId).map { user =>
          block(new RequestWithUser(user, request))
        } getOrElse {
          Future.successful(NotFound)
        }
      }
    }

case class AuthenticatedRequest[A](user: models.User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object Authorized extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        userTokenForm.bindFromRequest()(request).fold(
                formWithErrors => {
                    resolve(Results.Unauthorized(formWithErrors.errorsAsJson))
                },
                userData => {
                    models.UsersDAO.findByToken(userData.token) map { user=>
                      block(AuthenticatedRequest(user, request))
                    } getOrElse {
                      resolve(Results.Unauthorized("Token matched no one."))
                    }
                }
                )
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to compose them into a third action potentially called "UserPermissionAction" which composes Authorized and UserAction.
It should check if the Authorized user is the same as user in the RequestWithUser (i.e. only allow users to edit themselves).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.
it works but I'd like to see feedback if there is more idiomatic Scala way:

```
        /** Contains the security token, extracted from the RequestHeader */
    case class AuthenticatedRequest[A](user: models.User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

   case class AuthorizedAction[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {
      lazy val parser = action.parser
      def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
        userTokenForm.bindFromRequest()(request).fold(
                formWithErrors => {
                    resolve(Results.Unauthorized(formWithErrors.errorsAsJson))
                },
                userData => {
                    models.UsersDAO.findByToken(userData.token) map { user=>
                      action(AuthenticatedRequest(user, request))
                    } getOrElse {
                      resolve(Results.Unauthorized("Token matched no one."))
                    }
                }
                )
      }
    }


   class RequestWithUser[A](val user: models.User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

   case class UserAction[A](userId: Long, action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {
      lazy val parser = action.parser
      def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
        models.UsersDAO.findById(userId).map { user =>
          action(new RequestWithUser(user, request))
        } getOrElse {
          Future.successful(NotFound)
        }
      }
    }

   def UserHasPermission[A](userId: Long)  = new  ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
      def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        request match {
          case req: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => {
            {
            for (
                authUserId <- req.user.id
                if authUserId == userId
                ) yield block(req)
            } getOrElse Future.successful(Unauthorized)
          }
          case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest)
        }
      }
      override def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]) = UserAction(userId, AuthorizedAction(action) )
    }
```